# How do AES Substitution box's offer any additional security since it's 1 to 1?

Tags: aes, s-boxes, substitution-cipher, rijndael, frequency-analysis

If the Substitution box is 1 to 1 (a specific value can only ever be a specific box value), and the contents of Rijndael S-box is public, how does this offer any additional security?

With AES the frequency of a letter isn't a concern so what other reason is there for this substitution? An explanation fitting for a novice would be very much appreciated!

Additionally, why is Rijndael S-box a multiplicative inverse and what purpose does that serve?

Comment: \[Not a substitute for a full answer\]: Sure, a one-one substitution alone brings no security. However, adding XOR with key(s), it can offer security. For example, one of the simplest secure block cipher (known as Even-Mansour) is built from any large, apparently arbitrary, public, invertible one-one substitution $G$, as $E_{(k_1,k_2)}(b)=G(b\oplus k_1)\oplus k_2$ and $D_{(k_1,k_2)}(b)=G^{-1}(b\oplus k_2)\oplus k_1$. AES extends that in several ways: multiple rounds instead of one, round keys derived from the main key, $G$ built from 16 uses of the S-box and linear algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Philosophically *any invertible cipher* (it would be useless if not invertible) is just a one to one map, so no cipher would be secure under your argument.

Specifically, the Sbox has been carefully designed. For example, considering the linear and differential cryptanalysis attacks, having a nonlinear s-box mapping provides security agains linear cryptanalysis while having a low differential uniformity provides security against linear cryptanalysis. The AES Sbox has been optimized with respect to those attacks so it has *high nonlinearity* and low *differential uniformity*.

If the Sbox was linear then having 2 input output pairs we could determine what it would give for the sum of those pairs as well which leads to divide and conquer attacks.

$$
S(x_1)=y_1,S(x_2)=y_2 \Rightarrow S(x_1\oplus x_2)=y_1\oplus y_2
$$
where all quantities are 8 bit binary vectors. For AES, the Sbox has been designed to be as far away from linear as possible and *it is the only nonlinear part* of the AES encryption mapping. So AES would be trivially breakable with only $128$ known plaintext/ciphertext pairs if the Sbox was not nonlinear. See

[How can AES-like block cipher without non-linear component be broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/how-can-aes-like-block-cipher-without-non-linear-component-be-broken)

The link below is about minimizing nonlinearity for a boolean function, so just one output bit of the Sbox. By considering all linear combinations of the outputs of the Sbox we obtain low nonlinearity for the Sbox which has 8 bit outputs, i.e., it is a vectorial boolean function.

[how to calculate the non linearity of each element of s box?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53898/how-to-calculate-the-non-linearity-of-each-element-of-s-box/53900#53900)

For resistance against differential cryptanalysis see this answer:

[Searching for a differential characteristic (differential cryptanalysis)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68755/searching-for-a-differential-characteristic-differential-cryptanalysis/68760#68760)

The goal here is to stop attacks using input pairs $(x,x\oplus d)$ which may give output pairs $(S(x),S(x\oplus d):=(y,y\oplus d')$ where the quantity $d'$ occurs much more than the possible minimum, over all pairs.

The tutorial [by Heys](http://www.cs.bc.edu/%7Estraubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf) is a great introduction to these topics.